Why is the excitation energy of antiferro 1/2 spin XXZ chain associated with the $\psi_{n+2}$ and $\psi_{n-2}$
I do not understand the equation on page 5 of nagaoso's book "quantum field theory in strongly correlated electronic systems".
The Hamiltonian is shown in this form
$H=\frac{J_\bot}{2}\sum_{i}(S_i^+S_{i+1}^-+S_i^-S_{i+1}^+)+\frac{J_z}{2}\sum_iS_i^zS_{i+1}^z$
and the ground state is
$|singlet\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle-|-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle)$.
Assume the Ising limit $J_z\gg J_{\bot}>0$ and consider the state containing one domain wall. Calling $\Psi_n$ the wave function of the state where a domain wall is present bewteen site n and n+1, then obtain
$(H-E_{Neel})\Psi_n=\frac{J_z}{2}\Psi_n+\frac{J_{\bot}}{2}(\Psi_{n+2}+\Psi_{n-2}).$
Question: I do not understand why $\Psi_{n+2}$ and $\Psi_{n-2}$ come in the equation.
The figure below is the screenshot of the content on page 5.


As a suggestion, if you don't get a response here, you may want to try and email the author:  Naoto Nagaosa-Group Director  nagaosa[at]riken.jp and report back the response here for the benefit of others who may have the same question.    (reference: https://cems.riken.jp/en/laboratory/sctrg)

When the off-diagonal terms in the Hamiltonian (those proportional to $J_\perp$) hit $\Psi_n$ you have only two terms surviving. When $S^-\otimes S^+$ hits the sites $(n-1,n)$ you get $\Psi_{n-2}$. When $S^+\otimes S^-$ hits the sites $(n+1,n+2)$ you get $\Psi_{n+2}$.

Thanks. I have already understood the meanings of operator $S^\pm$, but what is the meaning of the term $E_{Neel}$?

$E_{Neel}$ is the value of the term proportional to $J_z$ applied to the Neel state. The approximation here is to treat the Neel state as the ground state and the domain walls as the first excitations above the ground state. This approximation is known to be quite wrong (especially in 1D), but I assume the author has good reasons to present it.
